# Monte Carlo simulation for the harmonic oscillator

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, physics, markov-chain

Is there any improvement that can be made to the following code, written to simulate the harmonic oscillator in the path integral formulation with Monte Carlo methods?

```
#STRAIGHT-LINE INITIALIZATION
def cold_path(N):

    return np.zeros(N)

#RANDOM PATH INITIALIZATION
def hot_path(N):
    
    return np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)
  
#MONTE CARLO SIMULATION
def Metropolis_HO(start,N,eta,delta,ntimes):
       
    #Set path at initial step
    if start=='cold':
        path=cold_path(N)
        
    elif start=='hot':
        path=hot_path(N)
      
    else: 
        raise Exception('Choose either hot or cold starting path configuration.')
    
    #Initialize arrays of observables
    obs1=np.zeros(ntimes)
    obs2=np.zeros(ntimes)
    
    #Useful constants
    c1=1./eta
    c2=(1./eta+eta/2.)
    
    #Iterate loop on all sites
    for i in range(ntimes):
        for j in range(N):
            for repeat in range(3):
                
                #Set y as j-th point on path
                y=path[j]

                #Propose modification
                y_p=np.random.uniform(y-delta,y+delta)

                #Calculate accept probability
                force=path[(j+1)%N]+path[(j-1)]
                p_ratio=c1*y_p*force-c2*(y_p**2)-c1*y*force+c2*(y**2)

                #Accept-reject
                if np.random.rand()<min(np.exp(p_ratio),1):
                    path[j]=y_p
            
        #Average of y^2 on the path
        obs1[i]=np.average(path**2)
        
        #Average of Delta y^2 on the path
        temp=0.
        for k in range(N):
            temp+=(path[k]-path[(k+1)%N])**2
        obs2[i]=temp/N
    
    #Get rid of non-equilibrium states and decorrelate
    n_corr=1
    n_term=10000
    
    obs1=obs1[n_term:ntimes:n_corr]
    obs2=obs2[n_term:ntimes:n_corr]
    
    return obs1,obs2
```

Comment: Please show example invocation, including typical values for start, n, eta, delta and ntimes.

Comment: Currently `force[j]` depends on the recently-updated value from `force[j-1]`. Can you accept the results if this is made to depend only on the previous iteration and not the current one? If so this can be given a large speedup. If not I think you're basically stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a lot of value in the "path start" mechanism. Just pass in a starting path vector, and assume N to be the size of this vector.

Don't capitalise method names in Python.

This form of comment:

```
#MONTE CARLO SIMULATION
def Metropolis_HO(start,N,eta,delta,ntimes):
```

should actually be a docstring:

```
def metropolis_ho(path: np.ndarray, eta: float, delta: float, ntimes: int) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,
    np.ndarray,
]:
    """Monte Carlo Simulation"""
```

Add PEP484 typehints to your signatures (example above).

`obs1=np.zeros` should actually use `np.empty()`.

This:

```
    c1=1./eta
    c2=(1./eta+eta/2.)
```

is really just

```
    c1 = 1/eta
    c2 = c1 + eta/2
```

`repeat` is unused, so name it `_` (the convention for unused loop variables).

This:

```
            p_ratio=c1*y_p*force-c2*(y_p**2)-c1*y*force+c2*(y**2)
```

is clearer as

```
            p_ratio = c1*force*(y_p - y) + c2*(y*y - y_p*y_p)
```

In this expression, the `min` is not necessary:

```
 if np.random.rand()<min(np.exp(p_ratio),1):
```

because `rand()` itself ranges from 0 through 1, and so an `exp` producing a value above 1 will not make the behaviour any different.

This expression:

```
    obs1[i]=np.average(path**2)
```

can be re-expressed as a self-dot product which might help marginally with speed; it will look like

```
    obs1[i] = np.dot(path, path)/n
```

Avoid this loop:

```
    temp=0.
    for k in range(N):
        temp+=(path[k]-path[(k+1)%N])**2
    obs2[i]=temp/N
```

Instead, use the same self-dot product trick, but on a `roll()`ed array:

```
    diff = path - np.roll(path, -1)
    obs2[i] = np.dot(diff, diff)/n
```

Your non-equilibrium filter is trouble. It arbitrarily starts the output at element 10,000 when that should be parametric (*especially* for callers that use a small value of `ntimes`). Since `n_corr` is always 1, delete it. And since the slice always terminates at the end of the array, remove that, too. That leaves us with

```
n_term = equilibrium_start
obs1 = obs1[n_term:]
obs2 = obs2[n_term:]
```

Add tests, at least for regression. This ties in with another important concept: even though your algorithm relies on random behaviour, it should be repeatable based on a seed. Best to pass in the newer Numpy random generator interface.

If you can turn the loop-pair of `for j in range(n):` / `for _ in range(3):` inside out so that `j` becomes the innermost index, then this can be further vectorised. If not, you're stuck.

### Suggested

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng, Generator


def metropolis_ho(
    path: np.ndarray,
    rand: Generator,
    eta: float,
    delta: float,
    ntimes: int,
    equilibrium_start: int = 10_000,
) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # observables 1
    np.ndarray,  # observables 2
]:
    """Monte Carlo Simulation"""
    n = len(path)

    # Initialize arrays of observables
    obs1 = np.empty(ntimes)
    obs2 = np.empty(ntimes)

    # Useful constants
    c1 = 1/eta
    c2 = c1 + eta/2

    # Iterate loop on all sites
    for i in range(ntimes):
        for j in range(n):
            for _ in range(3):
                # Set y as j-th point on path
                y = path[j]

                # Propose modification
                y_p = rand.uniform(y - delta, y + delta)

                # Calculate accept probability
                force = path[(j + 1) % n] + path[j - 1]
                p_ratio = c1*force*(y_p - y) + c2*(y*y - y_p*y_p)

                # Accept-reject
                if rand.random() < np.exp(p_ratio):
                    path[j] = y_p

        # Average of y^2 on the path
        obs1[i] = np.dot(path, path)/n

        # Average of Delta y^2 on the path
        diff = path - np.roll(path, -1)
        obs2[i] = np.dot(diff, diff)/n

    # Get rid of non-equilibrium states and decorrelate
    n_term = equilibrium_start
    obs1 = obs1[n_term:]
    obs2 = obs2[n_term:]

    return obs1, obs2


def main() -> None:
    hot = True
    n = 400
    rand: Generator = default_rng(seed=0)

    if hot:
        start = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=n)
    else:
        start = np.zeros(n)

    obs1, obs2 = metropolis_ho(
        path=start,
        rand=rand,
        eta=0.6,
        delta=0.1,
        ntimes=50,
        equilibrium_start=10,
    )

    assert np.allclose(
        obs1,
        np.array([
            0.33481635, 0.33975680, 0.33848696, 0.33565933, 0.34104504,
            0.33577587, 0.34060038, 0.34019111, 0.34048678, 0.34476147,
            0.34417650, 0.34058942, 0.34307716, 0.34851236, 0.33542469,
            0.33176036, 0.32263985, 0.33208625, 0.33240874, 0.32467590,
            0.32252395, 0.32424555, 0.32694504, 0.33374541, 0.32667225,
            0.32566617, 0.31967787, 0.32302223, 0.31925758, 0.32326829,
            0.32998249, 0.33500381, 0.34054321, 0.34033330, 0.33718049,
            0.33962281, 0.33585350, 0.34389458, 0.34816599, 0.34695869,
        ]),
    )

    assert np.allclose(
        obs2,
        np.array([
            0.60471689, 0.60145567, 0.59598397, 0.57394761, 0.58472186,
            0.56454233, 0.56965071, 0.55589532, 0.55379822, 0.54761523,
            0.5447842 , 0.54175528, 0.53238427, 0.53223468, 0.51024062,
            0.48941357, 0.47810786, 0.50182631, 0.48789695, 0.47479243,
            0.46272811, 0.45823329, 0.45743116, 0.46647511, 0.45989627,
            0.46653626, 0.45287477, 0.44861666, 0.43814114, 0.44599284,
            0.44905000, 0.46638112, 0.46607791, 0.45834453, 0.44513739,
            0.44357120, 0.43453803, 0.43544248, 0.44287501, 0.42685933,
        ]),
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for you answer. I'll take a little while to consider everything you changed (I am still very much a beginner). I just wanted to ask: are you also familiar with the underlying physical problem in the question, or are you only able to provide coding tips?

Comment: You haven't described the physics so I can't comment on it. At this point major modifications to the question are effectively disallowed because an answer is in place. If you want a second round of review, incorporate the feedback from this one (asking questions as comments here if needed), and then post a second question. Further coding improvements will be covered with this site. Depending on the physics questions, they might be covered here too (if they're about numerical implementation) or on physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm still new to SE, so thank you again for clearing that up. I might post a question starting from your excellent answer then, once I have digested it well. Meanwhile I will accept it :)

Comment: Meanwhile, I'd like to ask you a question: what is the purpose of those big assert statements in the main function?

Comment: By the way, I have followed your advice and asked a follow-up question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280525/calculating-the-energy-of-the-harmonic-oscillator-using-a-monte-carlo-method), if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: The asserts constitute a regression test to make sure that the changes I introduced did not alter the output.