# Calculating the energy of the harmonic oscillator using a Monte Carlo method

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, physics, markov-chain

## The problem

The partition function for the quantum harmonic oscillator can be written in the path integral formulation as
$$Z\propto\int Dx(\tau)\exp\left(-\frac{S_E}{\hbar}\right)=\int Dx(\tau)\exp\left(-\frac{\int_0^{\beta \hbar}d\tau\left(\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2(\tau)+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2(\tau)\right)}{\hbar}\right) $$

To attack this problem numerically, we can make this quantity discrete by choosing a sequence of N points x1,...,xN on the path x(τ) with distance a between each other; rescaling these variables we can write
$$\frac{S_E^{discrete}}{\hbar}=\sum_{j=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{2\eta}(y_{j+1}-y_j)^2+\frac{\eta}{2}y_j^2\right) $$ where η=aω. The continuum is then recovered in the limit of small η.

In this discrete form, the internal energy of the system transforms as follows: $$\frac{U^{cont}}{\hbar\omega}=\partial_\beta\log Z=\hbar\omega\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{e^{N\eta}-1}\right) \  \Rightarrow \  \frac{U^{discrete}}{\hbar\omega}=\frac{1}{2\eta}-\frac{1}{2\eta^2}\langle \Delta y^2\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle y^2\rangle$$ where the averages are first taken over a single path, and then over all paths generated in the Monte Carlo simulation according to the distribution function $$p(y_1,...,y_N)=e^{-S_E^{discrete}/\hbar}.$$

My goal is to compute the internal energy and compare it to the theoretical value for various values of N, in function of the inverse temperature Nη.

## The algorithm

In order to sample paths that follow this distribution, we can employ a MCMC method based on the Metropolis algorithm:

> 1. Initialize the discrete path in a cold configuration (all zeros) or hot configuration (random numbers)
> 2. For each Monte Carlo sweep, loop on all j=1,...,N and propose to modify y_j with a uniformly sampled y_p in the interval [y_j-δ,y_j+δ] for some parameter δ.
> 3. The update is accepted with probability $$r=e^{-\Delta S_{E}^{discrete}},$$ where the difference in the action (between the original and the modified path) can be easily computed as
>    \begin{align*}
>    \Delta S_{E}^{discrete}&=(y^p)^2\left(\frac{\eta}{2}+\frac{1}{\eta}\right)-\frac{y^p}{\eta}(y_{j_0+1}+y_{j_0-1})-y_{j_0}^2\left(\frac{\eta}{2}+\frac{1}{\eta}\right)\\&-\frac{1}{2}y_{j_0}(y_{j_0+1}+y_{j_0-1}).
>    \end{align*}

## The code

As kindly reviewed by a user of this forum, I report here the code that I wrote of a MCMC simulation of the quantum harmonic oscillator in the path integral formulation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import default_rng, Generator
import time as tm

def metropolis_ho(
    path: np.ndarray,
    rand: Generator,
    eta: float,
    delta: float,
    ntimes: int,
    equilibrium_start: int = 10_000,
) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # observables 1
    np.ndarray,  # observables 2
]:
    """Monte Carlo Simulation"""
    n = len(path)

    # Initialize arrays of observables
    obs1 = np.empty(ntimes)
    obs2 = np.empty(ntimes)

    # Useful constants
    c1 = 1/eta
    c2 = c1 + eta/2

    # Iterate loop on all sites
    for i in range(ntimes):
        for j in range(n):
            for _ in range(3):
                # Set y as j-th point on path
                y = path[j]

                # Propose modification
                y_p = rand.uniform(y - delta, y + delta)

                # Calculate accept probability
                force = path[(j + 1) % n] + path[j - 1]
                p_ratio = c1*force*(y_p - y) + c2*(y*y - y_p*y_p)

                # Accept-reject
                if rand.random() < np.exp(p_ratio):
                    path[j] = y_p

        # Average of y^2 on the path
        obs1[i] = np.dot(path, path)/n

        # Average of Delta y^2 on the path
        diff = path - np.roll(path, -1)
        obs2[i] = np.dot(diff, diff)/n

    # Get rid of non-equilibrium states and decorrelate
    n_term = equilibrium_start
    obs1 = obs1[n_term:]
    obs2 = obs2[n_term:]

    return obs1, obs2

def U(obs1,obs2,eta):
    """Computes internal energy"""
    
    c1=1/(2*eta)
    c2=1/(2*eta**2)
    
    av1=np.average(obs1)
    av2=np.average(obs2)
    
    return c1-c2*av2+av1/2

def exact_U(n,eta):
    """"Theoretical expectation for internal energy"""
    
    return 0.5+1./(np.exp(n*eta)-1)
```

```
begin=tm.time()

#Initialize arrays to plot U(n)
n_array=np.asarray([5,10,15,20,25,30,40,50])
U_array=[]

for n in n_array:
    
    #Initialize path
    hot = True
    rand: Generator = default_rng(seed=0)

    if hot:
        start = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=n)
    else:
        start = np.zeros(n)
    
    #Run MCMC
    obs1, obs2 = metropolis_ho(
            path=start,
            rand=rand,
            eta=0.01,
            delta=1,
            ntimes=80000,
            equilibrium_start=1000,
    )
    
    #Compute energy
    U_array.append(U(obs1,obs2,eta=0.01))

plt.plot(np.dot(n_array,0.01),U_array,linestyle='None',marker='s',color='k')

#Set arrays for plotting exact U
n_array=np.arange(0.01,300,0.1)
exact_U_array=[]

for n in n_array:
    
    #Compute theoretical value
    exact_U_array.append(exact_U(n,eta))

plt.plot(np.dot(eta,n_array),exact_U_array,'b')
plt.ylim(0,12)
plt.xlim(0,3)
plt.show()

end=tm.time()
print(f"Total runtime: {end-begin}.")
```

## Results

[image]

Even without error bars, it is pretty evident that my results are just not that accurate. Can the code be improved or fixed in order to obtain a closer fit?

Comment: Can you explain why [tag:markov-chain] is relevant?  It's not obvious from the code description.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sorry, I hoped it would be clear from the 'theory' part. The generated paths constitute a Markov chain, as each path is obtained after a Monte Carlo sweep from the previous one. The goal is to reach an equilibrium where paths are generated according to the specified distribution.

Comment: Thanks - it wasn't obvious to me, but I think some of the theory went over my head.  It's been a quarter-century or more since I last had contact with Markov processes!

Comment: Which part of the algorithmic description corresponds to the loop over `range(3)`?

Comment: @Reinderien Good catch, that was not described there. It is actually a technique from a paper that is supposed to make everything better, but it's quite fuzzy and may probably be removed without consequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably get feedback more specific to the physics problem you are solving at physics.stackexchange.com
*[Thanks to Reinderien in the comments for clarification.]*

As for the code itself, there are some issues that may make debugging harder:

- Bad naming - names should explain what they are actually naming

```
# Useful constants
c1 = 1/eta
c2 = c1 + eta/2
```

I can't tell what c1 means by looking at its name.

```
def U(obs1,obs2,eta):
    """Computes internal energy"""
```

Should be named `get_internal_energy()`.

- Comments should explain **why**, not **what**

```
# Set y as j-th point on path
y = path[j]
```

I can see **what** it does by reading the code. The question is **why** do we need this line?

```
def U(obs1,obs2,eta):
    """Computes internal energy"""
```

You write in the docstring what should be in the name of the method.

- Inconsistent spacing

Your spacing is all over the place, though this issue is minor and can be fixed easily. Reformat the file (e.g. `Ctrl+Alt+L` in PyCharm) with whatever linter you're using, it inreases readability at zero cost.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Are you sure this is not the right site? I am not looking to fix the algorithm, which I believe is correct (although I may be proven wrong). Rather, I'm looking to improve the accuracy of the results. Anyway, I will make the fixes you suggested to the code.

Comment: @MyCodeisaFlyingCircus what does the accuracy of the results depends on if not the algorithm?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant changing the algorithm altogether. You may be right, I'm new to SE and don't really know the best site for this kind of questions. I posted this here because it seemed one of the most active and responsive of these sites.

Comment: It's fine here (asterisk). CRSE frequently welcomes issues of performance but not correctness. Performance may be time efficiency etc., or "numerical performance" as is the case here. I consider this to be on topic since the algorithm basically works; it just doesn't perform well.

Comment: All of that said, there is a case to be made that this question (especially now that it has excellent theoretical descriptions), with some reworking, would get feedback more specific to the numerical physics problem at physics.stackexchange.com. I think both sites offer different perspectives and it would be reasonable to cross post there.

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks again Reinderien. I'll look into making a (reasonably edited) post over there then!